# unable to find any wireless networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Recently my Desktop stopped being able to detect any wireless networks.  The night before it was working fine, then it couldn't detect them.  For a couple days I could fix it temporarily by restarting my computer but that no longer works.  My laptop sitting right next to it is able to detect the network fine.  Any ideas on what might be causing this kind of behavior?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your desktop uses what wireless NIC?  If it is USB, are there any other issues with that port?  Can you test that NIC on another computer?  Have you booted to a LiveCD of any version of Linux to eliminate your installed OS as a potential source of the problem?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable about hardware issues so please bare with me.  What's a NIC?  My wireless runs from a wireless card installed directly into the motherboard so it's not USB.  I tried in my install of Ubuntu and cannot get anything there either ruling out the OS as the source of the problem.

Comment: NIC = Network Interface Card or Controller.  Since it doesn't work with either OS, that means it is most likely the integrated controller itself.  It is doubtful you made any BIOS changes since it stopped working suddenly, and restarting would fix it temporarily.  If it is still detected by both OSes, but just won't pick up networks, it could be damage to the antenna connection at the motherboard... worth checking out.